# Angular : Style class on component tag

Tags: css, angular

Is it possible to apply class or style like this on component ?

Element component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-element',
  templateUrl: './element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./element.component.scss']
})
```

Container component template

```
<app-element class="button"></app-element>
```

Global.css

```
.button {
  background :red;
}
```

Comment: sure, why not? you can find your element in the devtools and it will be there. just add `display: inline-block` so it would be at least something rather just a line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's possible. and another way is to use `:host` in your component style:

```
:host(.customClass) {
  background: blue;
}
```

Also You can directly add styles to your component like this:

```
 :host {
      background: blue;
 }
```

Or in your .ts file:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'your-component',
   template: 'your-component.html',
   host: {'class': 'customClass'}
})
```

You can read more about `:host` [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host).